# поцизионирование блока

Tags: html, css

```css
.basket_border {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    float:left;  
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 30px 8px 10px 10px;
    position:relative;  
    min-width:25%;  
}
.basket_plus{
    text-align: center;    
    color: #f38104;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom:-7px;
    position:absolute;
    left:151px;
}

.basket_minus{    
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    bottom:-5px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;   
}

.basket_number{
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;   
    text-align:center;
    bottom:-2px;
    position:absolute;
    left:118px;    
    width:25px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size:0.8em ;
    outline:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 4px 2px -2px #bbb,1px 1px 1px 1px #bbb;  
}
```

```html
<div class="basket_border">
<div class="selected_product_image">
  <img src="images/product/Без имени-1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="basket_close">
  <img src="images/menu/bt_close_login_form.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="">
  <div class="basket_description"> product description </div>
</div>
<div class="basket_price_block">
  <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
  <div class="basket_price">
    <span class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
    <span>USD</span>
    <div class="basket_minus"> - </div>
    <input class="basket_number" name="basket_number" value="1" />
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

родитель `basket_border` имеет свойство `relative` , а `"+"` `"-"` и `input` имеют `absolute` , Меняя координаты этих самых абсолютов (а именно сдвигая вправо), они почему - то "вылазят" за пределы `basket_border`. Не могу понять почему

Comment: А почему они не должны вылазить за пределы родителя? Это нормальное поведение. Для более точного ответа добавьте css код данного фрагмента.

Comment: обновил вопрос с css

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Кажется тут всё весьма логично и в порядке нормы. Пожалуйста расскажите в чем именно проблема и какую задачу вы хотите решить?

Comment: нужно просто подвинуть классы с абсолютами правее на пикселей 20-30, ( но в случае масштабирования экрана  в + они вылазят за пределы бордера )

Comment: позиционируйте от правого угла элементы - не через `left`, а  через `right` например

Comment: от правого угла тоже самое получается. Что самое интересное что бы привести эти элементы в ту же позицию через `right` нужно в `-px` задавать коорд.

Comment: http://codepen.io/lexxl/pen/mVqeKV? если я правильно вас понял, то тут работает корректно. проверьте. задал позиции трем блокам через `right` и при увеличении масштаба страницы плюсы/минусы остаются на месте

Comment: в ссылке всё как надо, но у меня почему-то `right` сдвигает элементы не от края

Comment: видимо, у вас влияют соседние элементы, которые вы в вопрос не добавили. либо выложите более полный код, либо отследите через отладчик, что влияет на позицию, и методом тыка установите правильные значения)

Comment: так сделайте просто left меньше на  20 px

Answer (score 1):

решил следующим образом: нужно блоки `absolute` обернуть в отдельный `div`, который будет за пределами `basket_border` и отдельно его позиционировать